# How to perform sorting using MongoDB's aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, scala, aggregation-framework

I have a document named **Program** in **MongoDB 3.4** which contains fields `id`, `program_name`, `no_of_students` as shown below:

```
Program
    {
     "id": ObjectId("5a06509859000089ebe6f2ab"),
     "program_name": "BBA",
     "no_of_students": "50+"    
    },
    {
     "id": ObjectId("5a06509859000089ebe6f3ac"),
     "program_name": "BIM",
     "no_of_students": "40-50"  
    },
    {
     "id": ObjectId("5a06509859000089ebe6f4ad"),
     "program_name": "MBA",
     "no_of_students": "100+"   
    },
    {
     "id": ObjectId("5a06509859000089ebe6f5ae"),
     "program_name": "MIM",
     "no_of_students": "60-75"  
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Here in my scenario **`no_of_students`** cannot be an Integer because it can have range like values such as:

**`no_of_student`**

```
   "50-100"
   "100+"
   "10-50"
   "200-500"
```

Here I want to sort based on `no_of_students` using **MongoDB's aggregation framework**. After sorting is applied, the results should appear as shown below:

```
Program
    {
     "id": ObjectId("5a06509859000089ebe6f3ac"),
     "program_name": "BIM",
     "no_of_students": "40-50"  
    },
    {
     "id": ObjectId("5a06509859000089ebe6f2ab"),
     "program_name": "BBA",
     "no_of_students": "50+"    
    },
    {
     "id": ObjectId("5a06509859000089ebe6f5ae"),
     "program_name": "MIM",
     "no_of_students": "60-75"  
    },
    {
     "id": ObjectId("5a06509859000089ebe6f4ad"),
     "program_name": "MBA",
     "no_of_students": "100+"   
    }
```

Comment: the "No_of_students" field is string, you wont get the expected result on this.
try with $filter and $cond in aggregate.not sure on the result

Comment: There is only one correct solution here. Change the type of "No_of_students" field to something sortable.
At lease get a rid of "100+" and change it to range too.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort in mongo using the following command :

```
db.collection.find(query,fiels).sort({**key**:1});
```

Here, 1 means ascending and -1 means descending order.
In your case you can sort the result using:

```
db.class.find({}).sort({no_of_students:1})
```

But for a good result, store **no_of_student** as integer and not in format "50+" or "40-50"

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I cannot store `no_of_student` as Integer because of my requirements. Also I want to sort using mongo's aggregation. I have updated my question. Please review it.

Comment: @khanalsir You mention that your `no_of_students` field needs to be a string representing a range of values. With that constraint in mind I would add an additional field (eg. `sort_key`) which has a numeric value indicating the desired order of your string values. You can then include this value in an index which efficiently supports your common queries and sort order. For example, you could use the start value of each range: `"60-75"` students could have a `sort_key` of `60` , `"50+"` a `sort_key` of `50`, etc. Trying to calculate order via Aggregation won't be efficient or scalable.